# How to make KineticJS ToolTip shadow "touch" at the balloon attachment?

Tags: kineticjs

In the KineticJS Tutorial for ToolTips [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-label-tutorial/),
a label is shown with a shadow.  Is there a way to add perspective to the shadow so that it and it's shadow-casting balloon touch at the point of attachment to the underlying layer?

Please see google maps for examples of pins that have attached shadows.

Comment: Asked as an exercise for the developer...

Answer (score 0):

There's no in-built way to do this. There's only `shadowOffset` to determine position of shadow, but this will not give you perspective. You can try to draw a separate shape that functions as a shadow.